# Using old Android devices (as far back as Kitkat)

Tags: android

Are there any precautions or protocols to be followed when using older (abandoned) Android devices.
Do not use bluetooth? 
Do not connect to open(no WPA2) WIFI spots?
Use web-based services over applications?

Comment: Do not use for anything important? I'd not mind having my toddler use one to watch movies on a roadtrip...

Comment: Usually android phones doesn't get anymore updates after three year. The device might be able to update to the last supported patch for a specific version. But it will still leave you vulnerable to most of the attacks and bug surfaced later that point. But you could root your phone and install new custom rom to avoid security threats or your best option is to buy a new device. And the device with older OS is safe enough if you are not a target. Better be safe by installing apps only from the play store and avoid any banking transaction through the phone.